# how to groupBy dates of JSON data with help of Underscore.js library?

Tags: json, group-by, underscore.js, week-number

I have following JSON data:

```
var data = [
    { "allocated":"20", "unallocated":"2", "day":"01/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"12", "unallocated":"0", "day":"02/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"2", "unallocated":"18", "day":"03/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"22", "unallocated":"2", "day":"04/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"3", "unallocated":"13", "day":"05/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"6", "unallocated":"2.4", "day":"06/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"07/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"08/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"09/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"10/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"11/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"12/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"13/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"14/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"15/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"16/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"17/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"18/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"19/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"20/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"21/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"22/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"23/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"24/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"25/01/2014" }

]
```

Now i want to do GroupBy "WEEK" of this data. So, i need above data in forms of week. How it can be possible by using underscore.js library?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and underscore's `_.groupBy`, you could do the following:

```js
var data = [
    { "allocated":"20", "unallocated":"2", "day":"01/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"12", "unallocated":"0", "day":"02/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"2", "unallocated":"18", "day":"03/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"22", "unallocated":"2", "day":"04/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"3", "unallocated":"13", "day":"05/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"6", "unallocated":"2.4", "day":"06/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"07/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"08/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"09/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"10/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"11/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"12/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"13/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"14/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"15/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"16/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"17/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"18/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"19/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"20/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"21/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"22/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"23/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"24/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"24/05/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"25/01/2014" }

];

var groupedByYear = _.groupBy(data, function(item) {
    var dateMoment = moment(item.day,"DD/MM/YYYY");
    return dateMoment.week();
});

var weekDiv = document.getElementById("weeks").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(groupedByYear);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<div id="weeks"></div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your approach to answer. It seems looking a perfect solution. Just let me check. Thanks!

Comment: @mccannf can you assist me in my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135635/how-to-group-the-array-elemnts-from-json-using-d3-and-crossfilter